# buttons staying at bottom of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I'm trying to keep two buttons at the bottom of a viewport, and it works within jsfiddle.  However, once I put it into a webpage I get errors on lines 7 and 9 in the js.

```
function checkOffset() {
if($('#button-float').offset().top + $('#button-float').height() 
                                       >= $('#Footer').offset().top - 50)
    $('#button-float').css('position', 'absolute');
if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#Footer').offset().top)
    $('#button-float').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
$('#button-float')($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight);
}
$(document).scroll(function() {
checkOffset();
});
```

If I put it into script tags I keep getting errors.  And it just breaks in the browser.  Any help would be welcomed.

A working version can be seen here.

https://jsfiddle.net/damianbuttle/2bwyge6o/

Comment: Can you tell us what errors you are getting? Also, are you sure jQuery is loaded by the time you run this code?

Comment: I get the following errors:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function
checkOffset @ buttons.js:7
(anonymous function) @ buttons.js:10
n.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4435
r.handle @ jquery.js:4121

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax in the following line :

```
$('#button-float')($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight);
```

I guess it should be :

```
$('#button-float').css('height', $(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that and it places the buttons at the top and they disappear when I start scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JavaScript for that as CSS does the trick.

I fixed your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bwyge6o/1/) in these ways:

Moved `button-float` into your `footer`:

```
<div id="Footer">
  <div id="button-float">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="mysearches.html">my searches</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changed your footer's position to fixed, and changed its height to 50px:

```
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 2px solid #a4cd55;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Added a margin-bottom to your body:

```
body {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```